# AppCenter Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65

Tags: ios, react-native, appcenter

I'm getting this error on app center.

```
2022-08-09T02:05:47.7079680Z ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
2022-08-09T02:05:47.7080600Z 
2022-08-09T02:05:47.7081170Z 
2022-08-09T02:05:47.7082040Z The following build commands failed:
2022-08-09T02:05:47.7083230Z    Run custom shell script 'Run Script'
2022-08-09T02:05:47.7084130Z (1 failure)
2022-08-09T02:05:47.7660870Z ##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
2022-08-09T02:05:47.7682860Z ##[section]Finishing: Xcode build (signed)
2022-08-09T02:05:47.7854350Z ##[section]Starting: Xcode build (signed)
```

On my xcode I am able to build and archive without an error.

I also tried to the following

- manual signing
- disabled flipper
- delete and recreate provision and profile
- tried to recreate main.jsbundle - no luck
- pod update and clean
- deleting derived data

My packages

```
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "appcenter": "4.4.4",
    "appcenter-analytics": "4.4.4",
    "appcenter-crashes": "4.4.4",
```

- Any more suggestions? I've been working on this for days

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,

This worked on my end

- on ios delete Pods manually
- pod repo update
- pod install